# file reference with slash

Tags: reference

If I am referenceing a file (lets say an image file for it to display on a webpage) which is a few folders above, I can write "folder1/folder2/file.jpg". What does it mean if the reference starts with a slash like "/folder1/folder2/file.jpg"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leading slash means that the reference is starting from the root directory (absolute reference) vs. the current location (relative reference).